# Angular 2 append Component dynamic to DOM or template

Tags: javascript, components, angular

I'm planning to add a component dynamic to the DOM if show() is called.
I know there is a solution with ngIf or [hidden] to hide it and use it as a directive, but I'm not a fan of this solution because I don't want to declare it in my HTML.

```
  import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
  import {InfoData} from '../../model/InfoData';

  @Component({
    selector: 'Info',
    templateUrl: './components/pipes&parts/info.html',
    styleUrls: ['./components/pipes&parts/info.css']
  })

  export class Info{
    infoData: InfoData;

    public show(infoData: InfoData) {
      this.infoData= infoData;
      document.body.appendChild(elemDiv); <----- Here?
    }
  }
```

and then I declare this as a Provider so i can call show().

```
  import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
  import {Info} from './components/pipes&parts/Info';

  @Component({
    selector: 'Admin',
    templateUrl: './Admin.html',
    styleUrls: ['./Admin.css'],
    directives: [Info],
    providers: [Info]
  })

  export class Admin {
    constructor(private info: Info) {
    info.show(); <---- append the Info Element to DOM
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that you need to provide the `Info` component as providers to the other component. I'm not sure that it even works. You can leverage `Query` and `QueryView` to reference components used in another one:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'Admin',
  templateUrl: './Admin.html',
  styleUrls: ['./Admin.css'],
  directives: [Info]
})
export class Admin{
  constructor(private @Query(Info) info: QueryList<Info>) {
    info.first().show(); <---- append the Info Element to DOM
  }
}
```

Instead of adding the element within the `Info` component, you can dynamically add this component using the `DynamicComponentLoader` as suggested by Günter:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'Info',
  templateUrl: './components/pipes&parts/info.html',
  styleUrls: ['./components/pipes&parts/info.css']
})

export class Info{
      infoData: InfoData;

  public show(infoData: InfoData) {
    this.infoData= infoData;
    // No need to add the element dynamically
    // It's now part of the component template
    // document.body.appendChild(elemDiv); <----- Here?
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'Admin',
  //templateUrl: './Admin.html',
  // To show where the info element will be added
  template: `
    <div #dynamicChild>
      <!-- Info component will be added here -->
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./Admin.css'],
  directives: [Info]
})
export class Admin{
  constructor(private dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, private eltRef:ElementRef) {
    this._dcl.loadIntoLocation(Info, this._el, 'dynamicChild')
        .then(function(el) {
          // Instance of the newly added component
        });
  }
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: The `DynamicComponentLoader` is now deprecated :(

Comment: @NoémiSalaün yes but this Günter's answer could interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 ;-)

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE**

Use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()`

- https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader
- https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createComponent

For a full example see [Angular dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

**ORIGINAL**

**`DynamicComponentLoader` was removed long ago**

You can use [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html) for this purpose, but it's a bit cumbersome and has some issues related to bindings.

See also:

- http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/loading-components-dynamically-in-angular-2.0
- [DynamicComponentLoader breaks Data binding](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6223)
- [DynamicComponentLoader does not support inputs or outputs](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6326)
- [Initial Changedetection not working with DynamicComponentLoader](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3474)
- [Angular2: Two-way data binding on component dynamically inserted using DynamicComponentLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503903/angular2-two-way-data-binding-on-component-dynamically-inserted-using-dynamicco)
- [How to provide data to a @Component through DynamicComponentLoader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269281/how-to-provide-data-to-a-component-through-dynamiccomponentloader)
- [Angular2: Creating child components programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830548/angular2-creating-child-components-programmatically/30966000#30966000)

Comment: Can you have a look to this question please, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47655224/load-ngfor-inside-insertadjacenthtml.

Comment: Oh great you have been quicker than me providing the new links 