# Angular 2 : get formatted template from a component instance?

Tags: javascript, angular

## Context

I'm working on a project using Angular 2, TypeScript, @ngrx/store and SystemJS. I've built a module loader so I can build my application by assembling modules. What I'll show you first is the *main module*, which provide the root of my app (nav, router, subnav and the content zone).

Before to go further, I'll explain what I have, what I want and why. Check this screenshot :

[image: graphics]

You can see different **pages** (Account, Channel, Playlist...). Those pages are listed in the **mainNav**. Each pages provies a sub menu (named **sidenav** in this case) and a **content**. It's a pretty common design I know :).

Let's go deeper. I have a main angular component named **MainComponent**. This is my root component.

**main.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-view',
    directives: [ Devtools, MainNavComponent, SidenavLayoutComponent ],
    template: `
        <ngrx-devtools *ngIf="prodEnv === false"></ngrx-devtools>
        <cmp-main-nav></cmp-main-nav>
        <cmp-main-layout [prodEnv]="prodEnv"></cmp-main-layout>
    `
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/home',    name: 'Home',   component: HomeComponent,   useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/medias',  name: 'Medias', component: MediasComponent },
])
export class MainComponent {
    private prodEnv: boolean = initialState.prodEnv;

    constructor (private _router:Router, private _store:Store<AppStore>) {
        _router.subscribe(url => _store.dispatch(changeUrl(url)));
    }
}
```

Let's take a look at **MainNavComponent** which obviously... Render the **mainNav** part.

**mainNav.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'cmp-main-nav',
    directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, MainLinkComponent ],
    styleUrls: ['src/modules/component@main/src/styles/mainNav.css'],
    template: `
        <nav class="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <cmp-main-link [routeName]="['Home']" [icon]="'face'">Account</cmp-main-link>
                <cmp-main-link [routeName]="['Home']" [icon]="'face'">Channel</cmp-main-link>
                <cmp-main-link [routeName]="['Home']" [icon]="'face'">Playlist</cmp-main-link>
                <cmp-main-link [routeName]="['Home']" [icon]="'face'">Medias</cmp-main-link>
                <cmp-main-link [routeName]="['Home']" [icon]="'face'">Security</cmp-main-link>
            </ul>                    
        </nav>
    `
})
export class MainNavComponent { }
```

Finally, **sidenavLayout.component.ts** wrap inside an [angular material component](https://github.com/angular/material2) the **sidenav** and uses `router-outlet` to display the content provides by the host component (see **main.component.ts** :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'cmp-main-layout',
    directives: [ /* ... */ ],
    styleUrls: [ /* ... */ ],
    template: `
        <md-sidenav-layout [style.right]="prodEnv ? '' : '30%'" class="sidenav-layout-wrapper">            
            <md-sidenav class="sidenav" mode="side" [opened]="sidenavIsOpened">
                <ul>
                    <li><cmp-sidenav-link [icon]="'home'" [routeName]="['Home']">Home</cmp-sidenav-link></li>
                    <li><cmp-sidenav-link [icon]="'input'" [routeName]="['Medias']">Médias</cmp-sidenav-link></li>
                </ul>

                <button md-button (click)="closeSidenav()">CLOSE</button>
            </md-sidenav>

            <button md-button (click)="openSidenav()">OPEN</button>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </md-sidenav-layout>
    `
})
export class SidenavLayoutComponent {
    /* ... */
}
```

## And what do you want ?

I've previously said that I've built a module loader. I want my pages (account, channel...) to be modules. So one "module" provide me :

- a sidenav content (yes, pages have different sidebars)
- a content (it'll be put inside the green content zone)

At the moment, the sidebar is the same across all my app. I'm looking for a way to be able to update sidebar depending on the page.

## What have you tried ?

I've tried to remove the `SidenavLayoutComponent`. A page (Account for example) provides me an `AccountComponent`. This component contains the sidenav and the content. Then, I can include this `AccountComponent` via `<router-outlet>` in my **main.component.ts**.

But nope : let says I want to put some generic things inside my sidenav. I need to put this generic content on each *modules* (pages). I really want to have a *'root' sidenav. Then modules put content inside*. (There is other reasons but nevermind).

## What do you want ?

Take a look at this code. It have to be inside the `SidenavLayoutComponent` class:

```
updateSidenavContent() { 
    // @todo : retrieve the template of the host component (from the _router) and insert it into the template.
    // Maybe using this :
    // this._router._outlet._componentRef.__zone_symbol__value.instance
}

constructor (private _router:Router) {
    // only if the host component have changed :)
    this._router.subscribe(route => this.updateSidenavContent()); 
}
```

**I want to get the formatted string representing a component's template from an instance (or the class but this is weird).**

### All this reading to ask this question ?!

I really doubt about retrieving the template like this to be a solution. So I've presented my case to make you able to find another solution, maybe better.

I'm relatively new to Angular 2 so maybe I've missed something important.

I don't want to present you all my environment and this "module loader" can be weird. I think all we need to know is here.

Thanks !

Comment: I know [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34856313/5542588). But I don't know if it's possible to add `directives` dynamically. I don't think so. **EDIT:** Maybe I don't need directive if I use `_router`. I'm trying this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add components dynamically use [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html).

You can use DI to configure what components to insert if that is helpful in your example..

```
 bootstrap(AppComponent, [provide('navComponent', {useValue: SomeNavComponent})]);
```

and then request it like

```
class AppComponent {
  constructor(@Inject('navComponent') private navComponent, 
       private dcl:DynamicComponentLoader, private elementRef:ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dcl.load...
  }
}
```

Hint: [OpaqueToken]](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/OpaqueToken-class.html) should be preferred over plain strings for DI keys.

You could also load routes dynamically with different routes (and different components) depending on configuration values.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In my case it'll be tricky to use DI. Check this : `this._router._outlet._componentRef.__zone_symbol__value.hostComponent`. Normally, `_outlet` is private. So do you know a way to get the host component without invoking private properties ?