# Dynamic HTML evaluation: show an <ion-icon> inside a HTML string

Tags: angular, ionic2

In an Ionic2 application, I want to render `<ion-icon>`s contained in an HTML string. The HTML string could be something along the lines of:

```
public explanation = "To open the menu, click the <ion-icon name='menu'></ion-icon> icon to the top left.";
```

The strings are stored in a translation file. When being output, I know that HTML strings are escaped by default and I tried to output the string with to prevent sanitization:

```
<p [innerHTML]="explanation"></p>
```

**Problem:** Now the `<ion-icon>` code is not escaped, but the icon does not render either (even though the node is present in the DOM). The code works well when using regular HTML like `<b>` tags.

**Dynamic template evaluation?**

I suspect the behavior is due to the fact that the code is directly inserted into the DOM and not evaluated by Ionic/Angular. For Angular1 there has been a [large discussion here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database). Solutions for Angular2 I have seen so far use [the deprecated DynamicComponentLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855718/angular-2-append-component-dynamic-to-dom-or-template) or [are fairly complex](http://blog.lacolaco.net/post/dynamic-component-creation-in-angular-2-rc-5/).

Is there any *easy* solution to showing the icon? Defining two translation strings `...LEFT_OF_ICON` and `...RIGHT_OF_ICON` would work in this case, but feels a bit awkward.

Answer (score 1):

Angular treats HTML added using `[innerHTML]="..."` as plain HTML and just adds it to the DOM without processing it in any way (no bindings, not directive or component instantiation).

You can use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` instead.

See [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468) for an example.

Comment: In the Plunker mentioned in the linked answer I can see that you need to pass a component factory of a specific component: `this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.componentFactory, 0);`. As in this case the component is used with its tag inside the HTML string, I cannot simply use this approach, right?

Comment: There is some support for CSS selectors but I haven't seen working examples. You need to create a component with that HTML in it's template, then you can add that component dynamically. This might be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008476/how-to-realize-website-with-hundreds-of-pages-in-angular2